# Retrieve data from another sheet based on key value without empty rows

Tags: google-sheets

This seems pretty straight forward, and I've seen some answers that come close, but I'm having trouble nailing down one specific requirement.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BaK3-xRuMqYSetMUs5oCyuEHaRzIz7FEZL641GrVFxE/edit?usp=sharing

What I want to do:

1. For each named sheet (Bob, Jim, Andy), I want to get the records/rows from "Owners" based on the name (ex Value "Bob" for sheet "Bob").
2. Each owner will have a max 5 records, for a total of 15 records in the "Owner" sheet.
3. I want to only return those 5 records for each named sheet, minus the "Owner" column.
4. I do not want to return empty rows, nor do I want to have to have 15 rows in each named sheet.
5. The data in the named sheets (Bob/Jim/Andy) needs to remain dynamic as I want to only have to edit data in the "Owners" sheet.
6. The data in the named sheets needs to be sortable by people with view-only privileges.

I've managed to get the corresponding data via:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("Bob",Sheet2!$A1:$G1,{2,3,4,5,6,7},FALSE)))
```

Issue with this solution:

1. Returns an empty row if nothing is found
2. Requires 15 rows in each named sheet to ensure no records/rows are missed.

Anyway, stuck, help much appreciated!

Update:

I managed to have a bit more success using QUERY, and running:

```
=QUERY(Owners!$A$2:$G$16, "select B where (A = 'Bob')")
```

And then having this at the top of each column. The issue here being that, while the results are initially sorted, any additional sorting (Z-A specifically) adds a large number of rows to the sheet (I'm getting a total of 510 rows after the sort).

Update 2:

Incorporated pnuts suggestion of:

```
=QUERY(Owners!$A$2:$G$16, "select B, C, D, E, F, G where (A = 'Bob')
```

Sorting issue remains an issue.

Comment: They appear sorted initially, but when you resort them (Z-A), the sheet adds empty rows (I'm getting 510 total rows after the sort).

Comment: Updated original question to clarify the sorting issue.

Comment: That's definitely cleaner in regards to getting all the data copied over, but it still suffers from the same sorting bug :( I also noticed that the Z->A sort doesn't actually work.

Comment: No, that would definitely work, but it defeats the purpose of having dynamically pulled data :/ I would have to manually copy/past every time I updated the "Owners" sheet.

Comment: Good point! Updated :)

Comment: Updated requirement for more clarification: re: users with view-only privileges needing to be able to sort data in the named sheets (Bob/Jim/Andy)